# GWT - Create a link to external website

Tags: gwt, hyperlink

I need to create a link that point to another website, not to the portal itself trought ajax call. I write this at the moment :

```
InlineLabel fv1=new InlineLabel("Validator W3C : ");
InlineHyperlink linkfv1 = new InlineHyperlink("HTML" , "http://validator.w3.org/");

InlineLabel fv2=new InlineLabel(" | ");
InlineHyperlink linkfv2 = new InlineHyperlink("CSS" , "http://jigsaw.w3.org/");
```

but it call the portal. In fact, if i click on HTML it adds #http://validator.w3.org/ in the navigation bar. How can I fix this? Bye

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The docs for `InlineLabel`](https://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/InlineHyperlink.html) say that it's meant to be used for "internal" links -- i.e., only to change the part after the #, like you're seeing.

You want to use [`Anchor`](https://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Anchor.html) -- this will result in an `<a>` tag being added to your page.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this solution:
Define an object of **HTML** class with the necessary parameters then add that object to a container in your GWT interface, FlowPanel for instance.

```
HTML link = new HTML("<a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com\" target=\"_blank\">Take me to stackoverflow</a>");
flowPanel.add(link);
```